# CSS Declaration for Input sequential <input id =" sequential list" > Generated by PHP

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input declaration (within a bootstrap modal) as follows:

```
<input type="range" id="seek-bar_<?php echo $i+1;?>" value="0" >
```

where `i` could be a large number.  I need the width of this bar to be 30px, so I added a class to the above to allow the width to be defined within the style class, i.e.

```
<input type="range" id="seek-bar_<?php echo $i+1;?>" value="0" class ="seek-bars" >
```

and then declared in my css file,

```
.seek-bars {
width: 30px;
 }
```

And no matter what this does not work, but declaring

```
#seek-bar_1 {
width: 30px;
```

}

does work?   So, I don't think there is anything wrong with my class definitions and declarations so it this will not work is there a way of declaring a wildcard id match?  For example #seek-bar_*.

I could just put the style declaration within the  tag but this will cause other problems for me and would like to have it resolved within my CSS file if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS **`[attribute^=value]`** selector. This selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value. In our case its `seek-bar_`. Like:

```
input[id^='seek-bar_'] {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Have a look at the example snippet below:

```css
input[id^='seek-bar_'] {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="seek-bar_one" />
<input type="text" id="seek-bar_two" />
<input type="text" id="seek-bar_three" />
<input type="text" id="seek-bar_four" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Saurav, this certainly answered the question and fixed the problem.